# how to insert data into datatable from variable

Tags: c#, datatable

I wanted to populate `DataTable` with the value taken from variable. I am doing coding in in c#. I have a `DataTable` called summary, I have created the columns and I need to add values to those from the variables `average`, `remaining_share`, `sales_proceed`, `cost_sale`, `realized_profit`.

The code is as below :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    average = 25;
    remaining_share = 30;
    sales_proceed = 125;
    cost_sale = 50;
    realized_profit = 33;
    var dataTablesummary = new DataTable();
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("average", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("Remaining share", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("sales_proceed", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("cost_sale", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("realized_profit", typeof(decimal));
}
```

I want to add values to `DataTable` on the button click, please tell how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `average, remaining_share, sales_proceed, cost_sale, realized_profit` are the variable you want to insert into the row, the following line

```
dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(average, remaining_share, sales_proceed, cost_sale, realized_profit);
```

will do it.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    average = 25;
    remaining_share = 30;
    sales_proceed = 125;
    cost_sale = 50;
    realized_profit = 33;
    var dataTablesummary = new DataTable();
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("average", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("Remaining share", typeof(decimal));     dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("sales_proceed", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("cost_sale", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("realized_profit", typeof(decimal));
    dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(average, remaining_share, sales_proceed, cost_sale, realized_profit);
}
```

Comment: @Darkknight: Welcome..:)

Answer (score 2):

you need to call newrow() of datatable instance. It return a datarow instance with row having same number of cell as the table has. Now u can bind data like this i have done.

```
 DataRow dr=dataTablesummary.NewRow();
 dr["average"] = average;
 dr["Remaining share"] = remaining_share;
 dr["cost_sale"] = sales_proceed;
 dr["realized_profit"] = realized_profit;
 dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(dr);
```

if colomn name u dont know u can write like

```
 DataRow dr=dataTablesummary.NewRow();
 dr[0] = average;
 dr[1] = remaining_share;
 dr[2] = sales_proceed;
 dr[3] = realized_profit;
 dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new row for `dataTablesummary` using `dataTablesummary.NewRow();` then assign values to the newly created row. and later add this row to the datatable:

```
 var dr = dataTablesummary.NewRow();
 dr["average"] = average;
 dr["Remaining share"] = remaining_share;
 dr["cost_sale"] = sales_proceed;
 dr["realized_profit"] = realized_profit;
 dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: @un-lucky : u r lucky for me... thanks for the help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a datarow of type dataTablesummary
DataRow dr=dataTablesummary.NewRow();    
//can be populated by methods like:
dr["average"] = 1.2;
dr["Remaining share"] = 5.7
dr["cost_sale"] = 5.4;
dr["realized_profit"] = 1.78;    
//Now add the row to datatable
dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(dr);
```

You can replace the numbers with variables